# Is there any way to convince GHC that this type parameter is phantom?

Tags: haskell

Consider the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}  -- used to make it very clear that the param is phantom
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RoleAnnotations #-}
module Test where
data Triv = Triv
data F (f :: * -> *) (a :: Triv) = F (f (F f a))
type role F nominal phantom
```

I expected it to work, given that the role of `a` seems quite clearly phantom to me. However:

```
/.../Test.hs:7:5: error:
    • Role mismatch on variable a:
        Annotation says phantom but role nominal is required
    • while checking a role annotation for ‘F’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Why is this? Is the type parameter *not* actually phantom (in the sense that, say, using `unsafeCoerce` to transform an `F Identity a` into an `F Identity b` could fail at runtime)? Or is GHC's role inference merely not up to this task? And, if the latter, is there any way to convince GHC that `a` is in fact phantom in this case?

Comment: N.B. The `f` in `F f a` may be a type family or data family, hence may dispatch on `a`.

Comment: @DanielWagner in order for such type family to dispatch on `a`, there needs to be more than one constructor of `Triv`.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin That turns out not to be the case. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The role is in fact not phantom. The following type-checks on at least GHC 7.8.4:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}  -- used to make it very clear that the param is phantom
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RoleAnnotations #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
module Test where
import GHC.Exts
data Triv = Triv
data F (f :: * -> *) (a :: Triv) = F (f (F f a))

type family Bad a
type instance Bad (F f 'Triv) = Int
type instance Bad (F f Any) = Bool

x = 3 :: Bad (F f 'Triv)
y = True :: Bad (F f Any)
```

This hole was plugged by the time of the 8.0 release (possibly before), but [there are others](https://gist.github.com/ekmett/ac881f3dba3f89ec03f8fdb1d8bf0a40) that seem more fundamental:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}  -- used to make it very clear that the param is phantom
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RoleAnnotations #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
module Test where
data Triv = Triv
data F (f :: * -> *) (a :: Triv) = F (f (F f a))

type family Succ :: Triv -> Triv

type family Bad a where
    Bad (F f 'Triv) = Int
    Bad (F f a) = Bool

x = 3 :: Bad (F f 'Triv)
y = True :: Bad (F f (Succ 'Triv))
```

And just in case you object that I can't write `F Bad`, it's easy to work around; you may add the following appendix to either of the previous two files.

```
data BadData a = BadData (Bad a)
xF :: F BadData 'Triv
xF = F (BadData x)
yF :: F BadData (Succ 'Triv)
yF = F (BadData y)
```

Comment: Wow! So this happens because the compiler doesn't want to prove that `Succ 'Triv ~ 'Triv`, even though it theoretically could, right?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin In fact this happens because of the exact opposite, namely, that `Succ 'Triv` is *not* equal to `'Triv`. There is further discussion of this trick [here](http://gelisam.blogspot.com/2017/11/computing-with-impossible-types.html).

Answer (score 1):

`f`'s parameter may have a nominal role. I need the `Triv` kind to have at least two inhabitants to show a counterexample.

```
data Triv = T1 | T2

data family K a :: *
data instance K (F K T1) = K1 Int Int
data instance K (F K T2) = K2 Double

coerce :: F K T1 -> F K T2
-- i.e., K (F K T1) -> K (F K T2)
-- That should not typecheck.
```

Comment: Right, but in the OP's example `Triv` has only one inhabitant.

Comment: I'm parsing this answer as saying "GHC's role inference is not up to the task" -- as in, there are some minor changes we could make to `Triv` that break coercion on F, so it's reasonable for GHC to be unable to infer that it's fine in this particular simple case. In the same vein, I predict that there's no way to have GHC let me type `coerce : F Identity a -> F Identity b` despite the fact that in the case of `Identity`, the roles of `f` and `a` are `representational` and `phantom` respectively. Is this correct?